# easy way to handle new content from dynamic populated tables?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've been with this for weeks and I couldn't find any "easy/fast" way for such mundane implementation. Im limited by knowing only php and html (at the moment) but I finally did get what I wanted using some javascript without knowing it at depth and I ended with a ugly few hundreds of code. But now that im more lightheaded I was wondering if there is some simple way to do this simple thing and improve my previous work:

I have a DB with Table1 with n Items and Table 2, I want to display the price from Table 1 then been able to input a quantity in the user side, and automatically show the row Subtotal, when all the items are populated, then show a Grandtotal as the user inputs data. Then read all the rows and insert the new info (quantity and subtotal) to the DB's Table2.

[image: Something like this but with n Rows]

Something like this but with n Rows
(yellow=DB data, Blue=User inputs, Greens=dynamic fields)

Then get all those n Rows into the DB
Any headlights for a simple way to do this?(even if it include Jquery or JS, im not THAT afraid to them anymore)
(I will not post my code because is crap, basically I ended listen all posible rows then inserting them on the Table2 if the subtotal was more than 0)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to dynamically change the `subtotal` and the `Grandtotal` as the user changes the `quantity`, you will need to use javascript, as php is only server side, not client side. Can you show a simplified code version of how you are creating your table (html) from your database?

Comment: Thanks for your time Sean!, yep, im aware of php being only server side, http://jsfiddle.net/1exp78zw/ this is pretty much what I ended up doing (the fiddle doesnt include the php dynamic rendering table1/brute force inserting to table 2)

Comment: In your jsFiddle, you have the `price` as an editable field/value. Is that correct? As in your description above, you only have the user changing the `quantity`, which in turn changes the `subtotal` and `Grandtotal`. Just want to make sure I understand your conditionals.

Comment: Testing your jsFiddle, it looks to work according to your parameters above. Is there something in that javascript code that is not working like you want? Or is your issue how to take the updated values, post them back to php, and insert them back into your database table?

Comment: Oh yeah, right, the Fiddle isnt mine, but it does pretty much what I ended doing, the Columns are switched in the Fiddle, I want to change the Quantity, the original coder wanted to change the price.

Comment: Im searching for a way to do what the jsfiddle do but feeded dynamically and as you say to posting them back into the database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130998/discussion-between-user3166200-and-sean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If hope this works

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mytable tr').each(function(i, elem) {
      var sub = $(elem).find('.sub');

      // Update subtotal after the price
      $(this).find('.price').change(function() {
        var quant = $(this).parent().next().children('.quant');

        sub.val($(this).val() * quant.val());

        updateGrand();
      });

      // Update subtotal after the quantity
      $(this).find('.quant').change(function() {
        var price = $(this).parent().prev().children('.price');

        sub.val($(this).val() * price.val());

        updateGrand();
      });
    });

    // Function for updating the grand total
    function updateGrand() {
      var sum = 0;

      $('#mytable .sub').each(function() {
        sum += parseInt($(this).val());
      });

      $('#grand span').text(sum);
    }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action "/someUrl" method="post">
  <table id="mytable">
    <tr>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Subtotal</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="price" name="price[]" value="0" min="1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="quant" name="quant[]" value="0" min="1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="sub" name="sub[]" value="0" readonly />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="price" name="price[]" value="0" min="1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="quant" name="quant[]" value="0" min="1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="sub" name="sub[]" value="0" readonly />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="price" name="price[]" value="0" min="1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="quant" name="quant[]" value="0" min="1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="sub" name="sub[]" value="0" readonly />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="price" name="price[]" value="0" min="1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="quant" name="quant[]" value="0" min="1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="sub" name="sub[]" value="0" readonly />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Grand total:</td>
      <td id="grand"><span>0</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The PHP code

```
<?php
// sample config
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "sample";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn -> connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn -> connect_error);
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $quant = $_POST['quant'];
    $sub = $_POST['sub'];

    foreach ($price as $key => $p) {
        $quantdb = $quant[$key];
        $subdb = $sub[$key];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO table2 (price, quantity, subtotal) VALUES ('$p', '$quantdb', '$subdb')";

        $conn->query($sql);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes its pretty much what I want to do, I managed to feed your code dynamically with php, but now its the second part, how do I store back the rows?
Thanks a lot for the code, its way cleaner than mine!

Comment: No, the table is filled with info from the database. then the user edits the quantity  and gets dynamic subtotals and grandtotal as he/she inputs data on the Quantity row. so far so good.

Now I need to store back the whole table into the DB, row by row I guess but I'm not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gqbbc649/ It will not work because theres no DB but is populating great (sorry I sended the last comment by error, cant edit it)

Comment: Could you explian me the following piece of code please?

function updateGrand() {
    var sum = 0;

    $('#mytable .sub span').each(function() {
      sum += parseInt($(this).text());
    });

    $('#grand span').text(sum);
  }
I guess if I manage to insert the data into a form field instead of the cell span I have what I wanted. thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much man I finally get it how to store back the data :) Im gonna mark your answer as the solution. Just one little thing, (my knowledge on Jquery is=0) If I want to store the Grand total back I have to put the dynamic result on a input field, like with all the others, but I don't know how to make your Jquery code do it, 
$('#grand span').text(sum);
#grand is the cell's name right? and span is well... its span, if I want to print the results on a text input, what should I do?
$('#grand inputname').text(sum);?
thanks for all mate!